# Change Images such as look like video

Tags: java, image, performance, swing

I want to load images in JFrame such a way that it should look like it is video.

For that I thought that I will change Images so much faster (20 images/sec.)

but Problem is when new Image get load its shows fully black window.

I dont know Why it happens.

Suggest me where I goes wrong.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

class VideoI extends JPanel {

    private Image img;
    private Graphics graphics;
    ImageIcon icon;

    VideoI(){
    icon=new ImageIcon("D:\\Videos\\1.jpg");
        add(icon);
    }

      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        graphics=g;
        repeatImgs();
        }

      public void repeatImgs(){
        for(int i=0;i<25;i++)
        {   try{
            img=ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\Videos\\"+i+".jpg"));
            graphics.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
            System.out.println(""+i);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(""+i+":"+e);}
        }


      }

    }

public class Video extends JFrame
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    new Video().start();
}

public void start()
{
    VideoI panel = new VideoI();

    add(panel);

      setVisible(true);

      setSize(1300,800);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
    }
```

Comment: 1) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details. 2) Don't attempt to load the images in the loop. 3) `graphics.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);` should be `graphics.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);` 4) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the flow.

Comment: Sorry For Trouble as I wrote code in bad manner.<br/>

I dont get your 2nd point. Can You Suggest me what can I do instead of using for loop???

Comment: The fix to Point 2 was basically to load the images in the constructor and simply keep them in an array or similar structure.

Comment: But It will use so much memory in my app.(I dont know weather I am ri8 or wrong). Isn't it???
beCause my all images is size of 100kb. (minimum)

Comment: *"(I dont know weather I am ri8 or wrong)"*  Avoid spelling like 'ri8' if you want my help..

Comment: If you are worried about memory usage, you can read the images to a queue in one thread, and fetch them from there in the drawing thread.

Comment: I am really sorry. from next time onwards I will keep this in my mind.


Really really sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are blocking the event dispatch thread. Use a swing [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to repaint the component at the desired frequency.

You should never, ever `sleep()` in the EDT. What you want is essentially

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // No loops or delays, just fetch the next image, preferrably it has been
    // already been loaded by another thread.
    g.drawImage(getNextImage(), 0, 0, null);
}
```

And a timer task:

```
ActionListener timerTask = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
        panel.repaint();
    }
};

Timer timer = new Timer(50, timerTask);
```

When you want to start the video, just call `timer.start()`.

Finally, you should also wrap creating the GUI with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.

Comment: where should I use this ??? (Timer timer=new Timer();) in main method or in my JFrame..
& I need to add ActionListernr???

Comment: The `Timer` declaration can go to multiple different places, depending on the design of your application. It can be a field of the video class, for instance. For quick testing you can put it as well be in your `start()` method. The `ActionListener` is the task that the `Timer` executes at every 50ms, don't worry about the interface name.

Comment: Thanks. It helps me a lot. Ill try & if It wont work I'll ask your help again.

Answer (score 1):

You're sending the Event Dispatch Thread (the UI update thread) to sleep, that's why you get screen issues.
Try loading and switching images in a worker thread (have a look at the `SwingWorker` JavaDoc).

Answer (score 1):

I'm no Swing expect, but I would guess this happens because you stop the Swing thread with the `Thread.sleep`. You should do the image changing and timing outside of the swing thread and use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to draw the Image. Also you need to sleep 50ms, not a whole second for 20fps. Using a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) whould fit here.

Also you always load the image from disc, when it needs to be rendered. This could be to slow. It would be better to load all image on start up and then just change the image.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get Some batter Idea. But can you Please Tell me how can I Load all Images on start up. & Still I think It'll make more burdon on my Application. Isn't it??

Comment: Just and another for loop which puts all the images (1.jpg - 25.jpg) in an list. Than access the list when showing the images. You will require more memory because the images are stored in memory. But otherwise the image loading may be to slow to load 20 images per second from disc.

Comment: I think It'll use much much memory(coz my all images is atlist of 100kb).